# re.findall filter for HTML

Tags: python, web-crawler, urllib, python-re

I am trying to teach myself Python, starting with a simple web crawler.
The basic goal is to get the URLs beginning with "Https://" and ending with ".html",
the first part is easy, but I can't "filter" for the .html part without problems.
I either get an error or no results:

```
import urllib, urllib.request, re

   with urllib.request.urlopen("https://www.TEST") as website:
       html = website.read().decode("utf-8")

   links = re.findall('"((https://).*?)"', html)

   print(links)
```

Comment: I highly recommended [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) for this instead of raw regex

Comment: Remember that regular expressions are "greedy" and will match as much as they can.  Thus, your .* is going to match everything up to the LAST double quote in the file, not the NEXT one.  Consider [^"]* -- "everything that is not a double quote".

Comment: @ Tim Roberts Thanks so much